# Multiple Wordpress sites on a single droplet / Virtual Host / One site is working, second gives white screen of death. Why? - Digital Ocean

Tags: virtualhost, wordpress, apache2, ubuntu-18.04, digital-ocean

This is not duplicated Post!

***System information**: LAMP installed on Ubuntu 18.04*

I have two WordPress websites on Digital Ocean droplet, let's say domain1 and domain2. I set up 2 virtual hosts.  My domain2 located on `/var/www/domain2` works fine but

domain1 is redirecting to `/var/www/html` instead of `/var/www/domain1`. Besides this, when I copy all files of domain1 to `/var/www/html` for testing purposes and hit to domain1, it's giving white screen of death.
**Additionally** : When I put a basic index.html file, it shows properly. But still it shows the index.html file of `/var/www/html`

let's encrypt already installed for both domains.

**Here the contents of relevant files:**

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/domain1.conf :**

```
    UseCanonicalName On

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin domain1@gmail.com

        ServerName domain1.com
        ServerAlias www.domain1.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1

        <Directory /var/www/domain1/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain1.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain1.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>
```

---

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/domain2.conf** :

```
    UseCanonicalName On

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin domain2@gmail.com

        ServerName domain2.com
        ServerAlias www.domain2.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2

        <Directory /var/www/domain2/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain2.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain2.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

---

There is a `-le-ssl.conf` file for domain2 (coming from let's encrypt). Strangely there is no this kind of file for domain1. I copied and renamed and configured for domain1 but still no luck.

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/domain2-le-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin domain2@gmail.com

        ServerName domain2.com
        ServerAlias www.domain2.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2

        <Directory /var/www/domain2/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Finally, `.htaccess` file which is the same for both of websites :

**.htaccess**

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I did these if you ask :

- Restart apache after configurations
- enabled the .conf files with a2ensite
- dissabled the 000-default.conf file with a2dissite

---

Edit: Also, when I google http://my.ip.address it redirects to https://domain1.com with white screen.

---

**Update**

Here the `apache2 error` logs could be related:

```
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31941] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.18.0.5. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

[php7:warn] [pid 12694] [client ] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0  [php7:error] [pid 12694] [client] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

Please note that: I changed the file permissions to 755, still it is the same.

Could be it be `ServerName` issue? : https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/apache-error-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-n
Here the vhosts file:

```
127.0.1.1 myhostname myhostname
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Stangely my hostname and hostname fqdn is the same. Is that okay?

Looking forward your answers!

Comment: What does `ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log` show for this request?

Comment: Hi @TeroKilkanen! Here these could be related:

`[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31941] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.18.0.5. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`

Comment: @TeroKilkanen `[php7:warn] [pid 12694] [client ] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
 [php7:error] [pid 12694] [client] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Please edit the question and add output error log output there, it can be formatted better there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shows that PHP cannot read `/var/www/html/index.php` because the file permissions do not allow it.

You need to make sure that file ownership and permissions allow PHP to read the file.

Comment: I changed the permissions to `755` but still, it gives white screen and it doesn't explain why virtual host redirects to `/var/www/html` instead of `/var/www/domain1` @TeroKilkanen Thanks!

Comment: Have you enabled `domain1` configuration with `a2ensite`?